# Drawing set of all points satisfy a property MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, set

I would like to draw set of points which satisfy a condition, for example :

`{(x,y) : x+y = 1}` or `{(x,y) : -xlog(x)-ylog(y)>10}` or `{(x,y,z) : x + yz^2 < 2}` 
(or any other property).

I couldn't find how to draw this things in matlab (I found only how to plot functions, couldn't find how to draw sets in plain). Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The equality and inequaliy conditions are two fundamentally different problems.

In the **equality** case you give values to `x` and solve for `y`. In your example:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,1000); %// values of x
y = 1-x; %// your equation, solved for y
plot(x,y, '.', 'markersize', 1) %// plot points ...
plot(x,y, '-', 'linewidth', 1) %// ... or plot lines joining the points
```

[image]

For the **inequality** you generate a grid of `x`, `y` points (using `ndgrid` for example) and keep only those the satisfy your condition. In your example:

```
[x, y] = ndgrid(linspace(-10,10)); %// values of x, y
ind = -x.*log(x)-y.*log(y)>10; %// logical index for values that fulfill the condition
plot(x(ind), y(ind), '.'); %// plot only the values given by ind
```

[image]

For **3D** the idea is the same, but you use [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) for the plotting. In this case the shape of the set may be harder to see from the graph. In your example:

```
[x y z] = ndgrid(linspace(-10,10,100));
ind = x + y.*z.^2 < 2;
plot3(x(ind), y(ind), z(ind), '.', 'markersize', 1);
```

[image]